# Emulation of Android Wear takes forever

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, wear-os

I am using Android Studio for running one of the default new projects themes however when I am emulating, it takes forever (it never really actually gets to the point I can see the app). I am wondering as if there are some underlying problems in the Android Studio setup?

[image]
Shows this and gets stuck:
[image]

This is what I see in my AVD control panel:

```
/Users/mona/Library/Android/sdk/tools/emulator -avd Android_Wear_Square_API_22 -netspeed full -netdelay none
```

and

```
Device Android_Wear_Square_API_22 [emulator-5554] is online, waiting for processes to start up..
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was I had installed the AVD device for arm while I should have installed the one for x86 as I have an Intel CPU. 
[image]

So in my case, you should install the Lollilop level 22 for x86 ABI instead of armeabi-v7a. Hope that helps.The emulator then should run the app within less than 60 seconds.